# Different memory types in System Monitor

Tags: memory, ram, system-monitor

On the ubuntu system monitor there are different types of memory listed: Virtual Memory, Resident Memory, Writeable Memory, Shared Memory & X Server Memory. What are the differences between them, and which reflects the actual RAM usage of the process?

Sorry if it's a newbie question :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- **Virtual memory** accounts for all the libraries and executable objects that are mapped into your process, as well as your stack space.
- **Resident memory** is the amount of memory that is actually in RAM.
- **Writable memory** is the amount of address space that your process has allocated with write privileges.
- **Shared memory** is memory that may be simultaneously accessed by multiple programs with an intent to provide communication among them or avoid redundant copies.
- **X server memory** is the amount used by the X server for the GUI-session.

#### References:

- ["Memory Management" on The Linux Documentation Project website](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html)
- [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562431/ubuntu-system-monitor-and-valgrind-to-discover-memory-leaks-in-c-applications)
- ["Shared memory" Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)

Comment: What about the column labelled "Memory"?  Is that a new column.  How is that different from all the other memory columns?  It's values seem to be smaller than Resident Memory in most cases.  Does that mean that it refers to a processes private memory only?

Comment: Added an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1344626/456255

Answer (score 3):

To add on to Ringtail's answer, the plain "Memory" column is `Resident - Shared`, giving you the memory that the process solely owns.

Answer (score 1):

Some definitions and wiki pages:

[Virtual_Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Memory)

[Shared Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory): The amount of shared memory used by a task. It simply reflects memory that could be potentially shared with other processes.

**Resident Memory**: typically refers to physical RAM installed in the machine

**X Server Memory**: Self explanatory, the amount of memory the X server is using (X server controls your user interface)

Hope I have clarified some things for you.