# Meaning of the 'Memory' column in the System Monitor

Tags: 20.04, ram, memory-usage, system-monitor

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/112407/1099647) explains the meaning of the columns `Shared Memory`,  `Virtual Memory` and `Resident Memory` in the System Monitor. However, the interface seems to have changed since that answer was written. I don't see any `Writable Memory` or `X Memory` column, and there is a column labelled just `Memory`.
What is the meaning of that column ?

(I'm using Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also wondered a lot about this issue of what does the gnome-system-monitor shows as memory in spite of having rss column. I didn't found any official documentation but discovered how memory is being calculated.

Basically resident memory is the actual physical memory it is using. Now rss also looks to be including the portion of shared memory of the process. So if you subtract the shared memory from the resident memory you get the memory portion that solely belongs to the specified process.

Hope this would've helped :)

Comment: thanks, that seems to be it !